# Как создать подобный эффект

Tags: javascript, css, parallax

Меня заинтересовал подобный эффект дыма, под которым находится изображение, см [здесь](https://youtu.be/wBpHcNPWSfA?t=168). Если не ошибаюсь, это разновидность параллакс эффекта. Каким образом это можно реализовать ? Может есть какие то готовые либы ?

Буду рад за любую помощь

Comment: не вижу параллакса, про какой эффкет речь?

Comment: вижу анимированную рамку(маску) с эффектом како-то то дыма что ли, речь про нее?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ думаю, что автор имел ввиду анимированную черную виньетку по границам картинки. Если сможете подсказать, то многие будут признательны

Comment: @letUser подсказать или попробовать реализавать ?:)

Comment: кстати в оригинале просто видео-маска наложена, причем еще и не затайленная нормально, как она дергается видно..

Comment: @StrangerintheQ попробовать реализовать вполне и сами могут, если интересно конечно :) а вот с помощью какого инструмента - это я думаю основной вопрос

Comment: @letUser я бы попробовал на webgl